# A simple proof for a case where: $\mathbf{L}_\mu \models ZF^-$?

Tags: set-theory

I am looking for a **simple** proof (no fine structure, please) of the following:

*Let $\lambda$ be a limit ordinal, and $\mu < \lambda$, infinite: If $\mathbf{L}_\lambda \models \texttt{"}\mu \mbox{ is a successor cardinal}\texttt{"}$ then $\mathbf{L}_\mu \models ZF^-$.*

Where $\mathbf{L}_\lambda \models \texttt{"}\alpha \mbox{ is a cardinal}\texttt{"}$, means here: *there is no  surjection $\xi \to \alpha$, in $\mathbf{L}_\lambda$, for $\xi < \alpha$*.

And $ZF^-$ is **Zermelo-Fraenkel** minus **Power Set**.

The proof I have uses some standard long-winded "condensation" arguments + Admissible sets. So I welcome any ideas.

Short of this, can anyone suggest a short, simple proof of the following:

*Let $\lambda$ be a limit ordinal [or even limit of limits]:
for all $x \in \mathbf{L}_\lambda$, there is in $\mathbf{L}_\lambda$ a surjection $\xi \to x$, where $\xi <\lambda$.*

**Note**: Devlin shows in Ch. B.5 of the *Handbook of Mathematical Logic*: 
*For every limit $\alpha$, there is a $\mathbf{\Sigma}_1(\mathbf{L}_\alpha)$ surjection $\alpha \to \mathbf{L}_\alpha$*

I am trying to avoid using this. Arguments using admissible sets are most definitely ok.

A reference to a published proof would be excellent!

Comment: There is no reason this should be simple and avoid fine structure.

Comment: Other than showing that $L_\mu$ is an elementary submodel of some appropriate $L_{\kappa^+}$, which I don't even think is necessarily true, how do you propose to prove this statement? It's a *strong* statement.

Answer (score 2):

*Here is a possible route for a proof, but I'm not 100% sure if the idea holds up. I'm posting it here as CW so others can make adjustments if necessary.*

---

**Step 1:** $\mu$ is an admissible ordinal.

This follows because if there was a $\Sigma_1(L_\mu)$ definition of a map from some $\gamma<\mu$ onto $L_\mu$ (or just onto $\mu$), then $L_\lambda$ wouldn't think that $\mu$ is a cardinal, let alone a successor cardinal.

**Corollary 1:** $L_\mu\models\sf KP$.

**Step 2:** $L_\lambda\models L_\mu\models\sf Replacement$.

Suppose that $\varphi$ defines a function $f\in L_\lambda$ from an element of $L_\mu$ to $L_\mu$, then since $L_\lambda$ satisfies that all the elements of $L_\mu$ have cardinality less than $\mu$, we get that in $L_\lambda$ this function must be bounded in $L_\mu$. In particular, we get full Replacement as far as $L_\lambda$ is concerned.

**Corollary 2:** $L_\mu\models\sf Replacement$.

And that's it. That's $\sf ZF^-$.

Comment: Alternatively to the first step, you can pretty easily prove Extensionality, Infinity, and Union from the definition of $L_\mu$ for a limit ordinal $\mu>\omega$.

Comment: Thanks Asaf for your sussgestions. I have the following remarks:
1. Your **Step 1** uses a result that's fairly involved, and for all I know uses Devlin's result which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: You can use the suggestion in my comment, and just prove the rest of the axioms by hand. That's not very hard, actually.

Comment: Thanks Asaf for your sussgestions. Sorry for my late reaction (life is harder, outside of mathematics...)

I have the following remarks:

1. Your **Step 1** uses a result that's fairly involved, and for all I know uses Devlin's result which I was trying to avoid. Do you know a direct proof of the result you are quoting?  A reference?

2. Your **Step 2** assumes that $\mu$ is regular in $\mathbf{L}_\lambda$. True, but requires an argument: essentially showing that if $\mu$ is the successor of $\kappa$ in $\mathbf{L}_\lambda$, then $\kappa$ is the largest cardinal in $\mathbf{L}_\mu$.

Comment: $\Sigma_0$ **Collection** is the problematic one. It requires some sort of downward LS result, in the restricted context of $\mathbf{L}_\lambda$ which takes some work. It can be done, but I don't see a simple argument.

Comment: Well. You said using admissible sets is okay. I'm not sure where's the problem. I'm just using the facts of $L$...